# MYSQL - Resultados mais recentes quando se agrupa por um certo campo

Tags: mysql, group-by

Tenho as seguintes tabelas no meu banco de dados MYSQL

Tabela USUARIOS

```
id | login
---------------
1  | usuario1
2  | usuario2
3  | usuario3
```

Tabela STATUS

```
id | idUsuario | data                | status
1  | 1         | 2018-05-10 10:00:00 | a
2  | 2         | 2018-05-15 10:00:00 | a
3  | 3         | 2018-05-20 10:00:00 | a
4  | 3         | 2018-05-20 11:00:00 | d
5  | 1         | 2018-05-15 11:00:00 | d
6  | 3         | 2018-05-25 10:00:00 | a
```

Como faço uma pesquisa na tabela de STATUS agrupando por `idUsuario` e mostrando apenas mostrando apenas os registros onde o `status` com a `data` mais recente é igual a `a`

Esse é o resultado que desejo alcançar com esta query:

```
idUsuario | data                | status
2         | 2018-05-15 10:00:00 | a
3         | 2018-05-25 10:00:00 | a
```

Alguma ideia de como chego a esse resultado da forma mais eficiente possível?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
SELECT idUsuario, MAX(data), status FROM STATUS
WHERE status = 'a'
GROUP BY idUsuario;
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado por tentar ajudar... já tentei fazer algo parecido e não deu certo porque nesse caso, como você está dizendo no WHERE que quer registros com o status = 'a' ele vai mostrar o registo de id 1 na tabela de status quando ele não deveria pegar nenhum registro com o idUsuario = 1, sendo que eu desativei o usuario 1 cinco dias e uma hora depois que ele foi ativado.